# Show that if $X$ is a bounded a subset of $\mathbb R$ then the closure of $\bar X$ is also bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that if $X$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ then the closure of $\bar X$ is also bounded.

### My attempt

I can show that if $A$ is bounded then so is $\bar A$. So if we have have limit point of $A$ say $a$, then there exists some sequence that approches $a$. Not sure where to go from here

Comment: You mention "also bounded", but never stated if $X$ is bounded itself.

Comment: fixed. Typo sorry

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is bounded, there exists some $M>0$ such that $A\subset [-M,M]$. Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in $A$ converging to some real number $a$. We know that $|a_n|\leq M$ for all $n$, so what can be said about $a$?

Comment: Can we say that since the sequence in A converges to some real number a, then a must be an adherent point of A?

Comment: What I was getting at is that $|a|\leq M$ as well, so $\overline{A}\subset[-M,M]$.

Comment: is this enough to prove it? don't we need to show a relationship between $A$ and $\bar A$?

Comment: Well $\overline{A}$ is the union of $A$ and its limit points, and every limit point of $A$ is the limit of a sequence in $A$, so this is enough.

Comment: You only need that $[-M,M]$ is closed, so if $A \subseteq M$, $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{M} = M$ as $M$ is closed.